# Run zip on command-line

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, zip, window

I have a bash file with this line

```
zip -q0X "../$1.epub" mimetype
```

But when I run this file on prompt, this error appear:

```
publish: line 4: zip: command not found
```

What can I do to run zip command? Is there a place to download zip binaries files?

Comment: http://cygwin.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you're trying to run a Unix command under Windows. While this is tecnically possible, as many utilities can be also compiled to run under Windows, they do not come installed by default.

You could run `zip` under [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), or else, try unzipping your archive with the command line version of [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Also, be sure that the dir holding your executables is in your PATH system variable.

Answer (score 0):

Zip for Windows is available from:
[Info-Zip for Windows](ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/), where you can get [Info-Zip 3.00 for Windows](ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/zip300xn.zip) or variations such as [Info-Zip 3.00 for 64-bit Windows](ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/zip300xn-x64.zip).  ([UnZip 6.00 for Windows](ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/unz600xn.exe), or an older [UnZip 5.52 for 64-bit Windows](ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/unz552xn-x64.exe), are also available.) and You'll likely need to either:

- extract the files to a location, and then make sure that location is added to your PATH
- or have the files extracted to a location in your PATH

if you want the script to work.

`-q0X` is supported, and means Quiet, Zero compression, including extended attributes.  Zero compression involves less CPU time, but more disk writing.  If you can change the script, `-q9X` ought to provide different results which you may, or may not, find to be superior.